# Typing "i" in search box opens inbox on mobile

Tags: bug, search, mobile-web, mobile-safari

I find myself unable to type the letter *i* in the search box here or meta.SE in the mobile view, because as soon as I do, the "supercollider" inbox opens.

I have keyboard shortcuts enabled in preferences, which is probably the reason I see this here as well as on e.g. [Super User](https://superuser.com/) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) (though not on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)).

I use the Grazing browser on an iPhone 5. I can repro this behavior on the default browser Safari as well.

Comment: Related/duplicate question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286345/295232